# Where did my second frame go?

Tags: html

When I look at this page in firefox, nothing after the first IFRAME is rendered.   Firebug doesn't even acknowledge they exist. In IE I see both IFRAMEs but only the "1" td, not 2 and 3.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Frame Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td><iframe src="frame1.html"></td>
<td>2</td>
<td><iframe src="frame2.html"></td>
<td>3</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Iframes must be well-formed (the tags must be closed). After each `<iframe>` add a `</iframe>` and your problem will be solved. See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3A2um/)